# Backpressure in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux

I'm quite new to Spring Webflux and the whole reactive idea in general. I've some questions about how Spring Webflux handles requests based on its reactive Publishers (Flux/Mono). Take for example a simple Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/planets")
public Mono<Void> createNewPlanets(Flux<Planet> planetFlux) {

    return planetService
                       .insert(planetFlux.limitRate(10))
                       .then();
}
```

I understand that limitRate() acts as a limiter for the downstream requests. My questions is, this backpressure mechanism is only acting based on single requests of my parameter (planetFlux). Does WebFlux (or reactive programming) in anyway address the issue of having a heavy load of requests? Meaning how would I go about optimizing the above code for multiple concurrent requests?

My 2nd question is where exactly are the remaining elements of planetFlux stored, assuming I apply some backpressure mechanism? Take the above code again, if I've 100 elements in planetFlux, where are the remaining 90 stored when my downstream processes it? Is it stored in a queue?

I would gladly read some reference if you've any. Hope my questions were clear enough.

Comment: here is the reference for backpressure https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_on_backpressure_and_ways_to_reshape_requests

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndolf. But I've read the official docs before and it doesn't answer both of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does WebFlux (or reactive programming) in anyway address the issue of having a heavy load of requests? Meaning how would I go about optimizing the above code for multiple concurrent requests

Webflux is designed at it's core for heavy loads of requests by moving away from the "one thread per request" ideom to instead implement event based chains where threads only work during emitted events.

As the documentation states:

> There are broadly two ways one can improve a program’s performance:
>
> - parallelize: use more threads and more hardware resources.
> - seek more efficiency in how current resources are used.

And reactive program tries to fulfil the second bullet point.

Your small piece of code has nothing to optimize, so i don't really understand what it is you want optimized, the insertion?

Someone subscribes to your service and posts a bunch of planets. You take that and limit the insert rate to 10 so that the insert method gets a Flux that will emit batches of 10 to insert into whatever it is you are inserting too. So i don't really understand your question here.

your second question:

> where exactly are the remaining elements of planetFlux stored

If you look in the source code you can see the following.

In a flux a single item is stored in the class `FluxJust<T>.class` as a straight up value. while multiple values are stored in the `FluxArray<T>.class` as a plain and simple array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again @Thomas. Sorry my question wasn't clear. I just wasn't sure of the flow of data from the request to my service. Say if I have many requests, each posting a Planet Flux of size 20, does limitRate(10) cater to multiple requests, (i.e. 10 from request A, then proceeding to the other 10 from A, then moving to 10 from request B) or is it specific to 1 request? 
Understood for your second answer though.

Comment: well you see controlling backpressure is what the `client` does, aka. the `subscriber` not your service that is the `publisher`. If you code in a `limit` on the `producer` side of things then it will affect all. But usually you don't do this. You write a `client` and it then has its limits coded in and sends backpressure commands to the `publisher` that will then send according to the clients demands.

Comment: But your service is a `client` to other services, or is a `client` to a database and you can then send them backpressure commands. You can limiting how many items you want them to send from say your reactive mongo instance. So you have to think about, who is the client to who.

Comment: I see. So the backpressure source should come from the client and not producer? Thanks a bunch again for your answers. This gives me a clearer picture of the reactive data flow. But I still have doubts on how requests are propagated amongst the threads and whether if there's multiple requests, the published results are in order or requests coming in or not. But I guess I'll just need to do more research. Appreciate your time!